# Why can't Java 7's new Path object relativize when only one Path includes a root element?

Tags: java, nio, java-7

As per [`java.nio.file.Path`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize%28java.nio.file.Path%29):

> A relative path cannot be constructed if only one of the paths have a root component.

Why is  this so? Why is it not possible to relativize like so:

```
Path path1 = Paths.get("/home/test");
Path path2 = Paths.get("home");

// throws an IllegalArgumentException
Path path3 = path1.relativize(path2);
```

I had imagined that `path3` would result in the relative path `../`. Why is it valid for `Path` to return a result that suggests that two directories sit at the same level within the file system if no root elements are defined, yet, when only one path defines a root element (as shown above), no relative path can be determined?

i.e.

```
Path path1 = Paths.get("home/test");
Path path2 = Paths.get("user");

// results in ../../user
Path path3 = path1.relativize(path2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A non-absolute path is relative to some *unspecified* base directory. If you have two such paths, it will make some sense to imagine they are relative to the *same* (but still unspecified) base directory, and then it makes meaning to ask where one is with respect to the other.

On the other hand, if you have two paths of which only one is absolute, such as `/home/test` and `home` there is no knowing what there relation is. For example if the base directory happens to be `/home/test/blah`, then `home` means `/home/test/blah/home` and it should therefore relativize to `blah/home`. But how would the method know how to invent `blah` (or to invent something else entirely)?

The whole point of using a relative path is to say, *I'm not telling you yet* what the base directory for this pathname is going to be. Expecting the runtime library to *guess* the base path that we're explicitly not telling it would be completely counter to that semantics.

Comment: why does it make 'some sense' to imagine they are relative to the same base directory? What if they're not?

Comment: It _may or may not_ make sense to assume that they will eventually have the same base directory, even if you don't know what it is yet. You're free not to use the function whenever you know it doesn't. On the other hand it _does not_ make any particular sense to assume that a non-absolute string will eventually be interpreted relative to the root. If you already know what the base will be, work with an absolute path instead. Out of all the cases where you know what the base is going to be, the ones where it is specifically `/` are rare enough not to make it a default, silent, assumption.